# remove header (and possibly footer) from iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to pull in this inventory list from [this equipment trader online](http://www.equipmenttraderonline.com/find/dealers/KO-Machinery/2991578/) webpage onto a separate site. I want to get rid of the header, and if possible, the footer, to try and keep users from wandering to another person's inventory. There are hardly any anchors on their divs, and using a non-scrollable iframe going to a specific anchor does work, but when the user clicks any of the units, it stops working.

Comment: **No.** You cannot modify the contents of an `iframe`. In any browser, that's a security constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read or modify the contents of an iframe from an outer frame. Your browser does this to protect you from someone setting up a site and putting your bank in an iframe then reading your account number, your address and your balance then taking all your money.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You could use margin-top: -1px; inside css to hide the top part of the page.